# Compile Tkinter application to executable using PyInstaller?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to compile my Tkinter application to a standalone executable on OSX 10.10.3, however when I run the compiled application my terminal shows

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/Users/rylan/Documents/PingerGUI/build/pingergui/out00-PYZ.pyz/Tkinter", line 39, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rylan/Documents/PingerGUI/dist/pingergui/_tkinter.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/Tcl
  Referenced from: /Users/rylan/Documents/PingerGUI/dist/pingergui/_tkinter.so
  Reason: image not found
logout

[Process completed]
```

I take this to mean that Tkinter isn't being loaded? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: you can edit the datas field to explicitly include the _tkinter.so file (sorry i dont know much about macs so I probably cant help too much)

Comment: @JoranBeasley How would I go about that? I'm new to Python, sorry :) Would you mind just pointing me in the right direction perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: edit the .spec file that is created and add someting like `datas += ["/path/to/_tkinter.so"]`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks anyways.